# Getting specific value from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In My Application i am Using ArcGIS . in that one i want Search one place and get the places related to that name. Now  I want to Parse all the address of that places and put them in a table View. after typing the address and after i press search Button i will get all the Markers on the Map. Now i'm trying to get the complete address of the Place But i was unable to do this.I want to get "place_addr" value from the below string can any one please help me how can i get that value in ios

```
AGSFindLocationResult name=Disneyland, extent=AGSEnvelope: xmin = -13129988.221853, ymin =       4000701.846518, xmax = -13124422.247314, ymax = 4007401.106877, spatial reference: [AGSSpatialReference: wkid = 102100, wkt = null], graphic=geometry: AGSPoint: x = -13127204.667522, y = 4004050.640580, spatial reference: [AGSSpatialReference: wkid = 102100, wkt = null], symbol: { AGSPictureMarkerSymbol: imageName: BluePushpin.png, width: 36.000000, height: 36.000000 },       attributes: {
AddBldg = "";
AddNum = "";
AddNumFrom = "";
AddNumTo = "";
"Addr_type" = POI;
City = Anaheim;
Country = USA;
DisplayX = "-117.923687";
DisplayY = "33.815467";
Distance = 0;
LangCode = "";
"Loc_name" = "Gaz.WorldGazetteer.POI2";
"Match_addr" = Disneyland;
Nbrhd = "";
Phone = "(714)781-4565";
PlaceName = Disneyland;
"Place_addr" = "1313 S Disneyland Dr Anaheim, CA 92802";
Postal = "";
PostalExt = "";
Rank = "2.5";
Region = California;
Score = 100;
Side = "";
StAddr = "";
StDir = "";
StName = "";
StPreDir = "";
StPreType = "";
StType = "";
Subregion = Orange;
Type = "Amusement Park";
URL = "";
X = "-117.923687";
Xmax = "-117.898691";
Xmin = "-117.948691";
Y = "33.815467";
Ymax = "33.84047000000002";
Ymin = "33.79047";
 },  visible: 1
```

Comment: your response is in array format.
Take value of first array in dictionary and fetch value from dictionary using key "place_addr"

Comment: Are you getting back that content as a string? It's not in JSON or XML format? That's unusual.

Answer (score 0):

IF what you're getting back really is a string, then you should look at the string searching methods like rangeOfString.

That will return an NSRange that contains your label, "place_addr".

Then you'd want to search from that point forward for a semicolon, using the related method rangeOfString:options:range:, that searches in a specific range of a string.

Finally, you'd need to calculate a range for the contents, that would be 5 characters past the end of the NSRange of "place_addr", and up to, but not including, the final semicolon.

Then you'd use substringWithRange to extract the string who's range you calculated above.

Give that a try, and come back if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below

```
- (NSArray *)findKey:(NSString *)key inString:(NSString *)allString
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    NSArray *splitArray = [allString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    for (NSString *s in splitArray) {
        NSArray * keyValueArry = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

        if([keyValueArry count] > 1)
        {
            NSString *_key = [keyValueArry objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *_value = [keyValueArry objectAtIndex:1];
            if([_key isEqualToString:key])
            {
                [result addObject:_value];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

where key is place_addr, and allString is as your sample string.